# Filtrar resultados por categoría con pestañas

Tags: php, html

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web pero tengo una gran duda: ¿cómo podría filtrar resultados por categoría?

Por ejemplo, le damos al botón <kbd>Imágenes</kbd> y me filtre todas las publicaciones por imágenes o al de <kbd>Noticias</kbd> y me filtre todas las publicaciones por noticias y los muestre en pantalla.

Para ser mas preciso estoy realizando un blog.

[image: Aspecto de las pestañas de selección de categoría]

Esa es la imagen de las pestañas que estoy utilizando.

A continuación muestro el código PHP que hace la consulta a la base de datos:

```
<?php
function categorias($conexion){
    $cat = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM categorias');
    $cat = $cat->execute();
    return $cat;
}
```

Y a continuación el HTML:

```
    <div class="tabs is-centered is-toggle is-fullwidth">
        <ul>
            <li class="is-active">
                <a href="index.php">
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-image" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span>Imagenes</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span>Musica</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-film" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span>Videos</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="far fa-file-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span>Noticias</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i></span>
                    <span>Arte</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span>
                    <span>Downloads</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Ahora yo tendríaa que realizar un bucle y mostrarlo si no me equivoco.

Comment: a tu consulta le deberás pasar una condición de tipo `WHERE categoria = $categoria` donde `$categoria` es el valor dinámico que el usuario pasa al interactuar con la web.... algo así

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar cómo estructuras las publicaciones en tu base de datos y cómo diferencias una categoría de otra? @element quizá quería decir `WHERE categoria = ?`. ¿Usas PDO/mysql o mysqli?

Comment: Como menciona @element, agrega un campo *categoria* a tu tabla. Y si selecciona imagenes, la consulta sería select * from tabla where categoria = 1. Si fuese musica select * from tabla where categoria = 2. Y asi sucesivamente